# Help in choosing the right type of database

Tags: mysql, nosql

As part of my learning, i am developing a google maps V3 application, to allow people to upload real estate and rental listings. I would like to know what database should i use? I am quite confused as i have researched mysql, coudb, cassandra, maria db and a whole lot more, the issue is that everyone has a + and - things to say with no consistent message, especially regarding RDMS VS No SQL, there is so much back and forth. Maybe anyone of these will be good enough, but i would like the guidance from some experienced developers here on which way to go. Thanks in advance...

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with the tried and tested - MySQL (or PostgreSQL) will almost certainly give you what you want, the world and its dog can help you out with SQL.

Once you've used one of those in anger, and realised its strengths and limitations, then you'll be much better placed to determine the merits (or otherwise) of an alternative.

For what it's worth, I've used MySQL since maybe 2000 in telecoms environments handling hundreds of thousands of calls a day for reporting, billing, logging, etc., and I see no good reason to change.

Comment: I hear you on this point, i learnt the hard way with javascript frameworks, spent a long time evaluating all and i was totally confused as everyone promoted the framework they liked, so i just decided to cut my teeth learning a few and after playing with jquery, dojo and sproutcore,i really understand the differences much better. I guess i should just cut my teeth on using a basic mysql and i will have a better feel for databases in general.

Comment: I just read about the CAP theorem, its starting to make a lot more sense now. Its funny how new technology can be over-hyped and be made to seem like a complete substitute rather than a complement.

Answer (score 1):

Choice of DB comes down to your requirements. If you're a bank, you need an RDBMS. Consistency and data integrity are your primary concerns, and the no-sql "databases" cannot provide that. If you're a big social networking site and can live with the occasional bit of unsychronized data in exchange for some speed, then go with one of the nosql type systems.

And of course, nothing says you can't go with a hybrid system. Critical "must be correct/consistent" data in an RDBMS, and the other "can be glitchy" stuff in a nosql.

Comment: Therefore if my application does any credit card processing, i should choose an RDBMS?